# Can't make Dialog Clickable

Tags: android, dialog, onclick

I can't make this dialog box clickable. I only want that it should contain an image, and that must be clickable. I have added the image, but I can't make it clickable.

```
Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(this);
settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
settingsDialog.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.iv, null));
settingsDialog.show();
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.iv, null);
ImageView im = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.<your image view ID>);
settingsDialog.setContentView(v);
im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @kkhanna Please post the answer as the solution and accept it then

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to do it by custom alert dialog,use this code

AlertDialog.Builder builder ;

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    //builder.setMessage("Do you want to Exit Scramble?")
          builder.setCancelable(false)
           .setIcon(R.drawable.sly)

           .setTitle("  ")
          .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dlg, int id) {
             finish();


       }

       });


    builder.show();

    }
```

Suppose if you dont want to have the OK button,surely you need to go for custom Alert dialog.Its very simple.refer this site: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Comment: This is the solution that i got and working

dialog = new Dialog(ImageDialog.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_layout);
    dialog.setTitle("This is my custom dialog box");
    dialog.setCancelable(true);         
    ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.tryin);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     {    
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.cancel();
    );      
    }
    });
    dialog.show();

Comment: great..you finally completed by Custom Dialog.Nice dude